# Changing the background color on mouse event

Tags: java, applet, mouseevent, awt

I want to change the background color when the mouse is clicked on the outside of the rectangle. I just dont know how to use the MouseEvent.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class AnAppletWithMouseEvents extends Applet implements MouseListener {
public void init()
{
    addMouseListener(this);
}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{

    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.drawRect(10, 30, 150, 150);
}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    String clickDesc;
    if (e.getClickCount() == 2)
        clickDesc = "double";
    else
        clickDesc = "single";

    System.out.println("Mouse was " + clickDesc + "-clicked at location (" +
        e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");

}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

Comment: So whats your problem? What is the output when you click anywhere?

Comment: Exactly what part are you having trouble with?  Does your `mouseClicked` method work?  If so, you have the point which the mouse was clicked and the bounds of the rectangle, what more do you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class AnAppletWithMouseEvents extends Applet implements MouseListener {
Color color = Color.green;
public void init()
{
    addMouseListener(this);
}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{

    g.setColor(this.color);
    g.drawRect(10, 30, 150, 150);
}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    this.color = color.red;
    this.repaint();

}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

Now you need to count if the click was outside the bounds of rectangle.

Comment: You should also add a check to see if the click is inside the rectangle, of course. But given the op's original code, he should understand how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In the `mouseClicked` method, you should test that `e.getX()` and `e.getY()` are outside the rectangle, and then invoke `setBackground()` :

`this.setBackground(Color.red);`

The rectangle border will stay green (is that what you want?)

HTH